# Chef Role not applying as a role but rather a recipe

Tags: chef-infra

After following the [documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_recipes_run_lists.html) from Opscode on how to upload and apply a Role to a chef-client, I received the `Updated Role Zabbix_Proxy_Standalone!` from my terminal. Then I attempted to apply the role to a node using:

`$ knife node run_list add MyServer.net 'role[Zabbix_Proxy_Standalone]'

run_list:  [recipe[roles]]`

Then when I ran `chef-client` on the target node, I received an error telling me that the cookbook `roles` did not exist on the server.

I also tried using single quotes around the role part of the statement, or taking out the underscore between run and list, still no dice. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen before however I'm not sure why it interprets the role as a recipe. As a workaround you can manually edit the JSON definition for the node:

```
knife node edit MyServer.net
```

You then need to change the run_list attribute:

```
{
  ...
  "run_list": [
    "role[Zabbix_Proxy_Standalone]"
  ]
}
```

Note: you will need to set the EDITOR environment variable to your favourite text editor for this to work.